# Missing factor levels after logistic regression glm()

Tags: r, regression, logistic, missing-data

I would like to perform a logistic regression on a marketing data set (only categorical variables), of the form [outcome, $X_1$,$X_2$,$X_3$,$X_4$,$X_5$,$X_6$]

I split the data set into a training set and a validation set.

My problem: Predictor $X_1$ has originally 3 levels. The model using glm retains only 2 of these 3 levels.

When I try to run the model on the validation set (where $X_1$ still has 3 levels) I get an error message stating that the factor $X_1$ has now a new level.

How can I prevent the glm function from excluding factor levels? I don't mind if their coefficients are set to zero.

Comment: Your problem is probably that while splitting to test/training you didn't make sure that each set contains all the possible levels of X1

Answer (score 5):

This line in `glm()` is doing you in:

```
mf$drop.unused.levels <- TRUE
```

which is effectively setting the argument of the same name of `model.frame()`, which results in the behaviour you report.

The obvious solution is to not allow this to happen, to adjust your split sampling algorithm you use to produce your training and test sets. Instead of randomly sampling the rows of the data randomly sample within the levels of the factor.

If you don't want to handle the details yourself, try the **caret** package and its function `createFolds()`:

```
## install.packages("caret")
library("caret")

X1 <- factor(rep(1:3, times = c(20, 30, 50))) ## dummy data for illustration
f <- createFolds(X1, k = 5)
f
```

which gives:

```
> f <- createFolds(X1, k = 5)
> f
$Fold1
 [1]  5  7 10 20 21 24 29 31 34 42 51 52 59 68 75 76 82 83
[19] 85 94

$Fold2
 [1]  4  9 11 18 22 23 30 38 40 44 55 58 62 66 70 72 80 81
[19] 87 92

$Fold3
 [1]  1 12 14 16 27 37 41 48 49 50 53 60 61 63 64 74 79 88
[19] 89 97

$Fold4
 [1]  3 15 17 19 25 28 32 35 36 43 54 57 67 69 71 73 78 86
[19] 98 99

$Fold5
 [1]   2   6   8  13  26  33  39  45  46  47  56  65  77  84
[15]  90  91  93  95  96 100
```

The values in `f` are the *indices* of the elements of `X1` partitioning it into `k = 5` groups, with sampling from within the levels of `X1` as needed. Then take 1 of these folds at random as the test set.

```
## number of samples in levels of X1 for each split
> table(X1[-f[[1]]])

 1  2  3 
16 24 40 
> table(X1[-f[[2]]])

 1  2  3 
16 24 40 
> table(X1[-f[[3]]])

 1  2  3 
16 24 40 
> table(X1[-f[[4]]])

 1  2  3 
16 24 40 
> table(X1[-f[[5]]])

 1  2  3 
16 24 40
```

Do note that this algorithm doesn't guarantee that for small sample sizes that the stratified sampling will always work (i.e you may not be able to escape the missing levels issue in all cases).